# Passing child component method to parent component on click event vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In my parent component i have an click event.The click event should display either student or staff pages based on condition.The child component should pass the method to parent which page should display.How can i pass the child methods to parents ?

- Parent Component

  ```
   <student @getStudent="getInfo"/>
   <staff @getStaff="getInfo"/>


  <div>
      <button @click="getInfo">Click</button>
  </div>

  methods: {
     getInfo() {
    if (this.type === 'student') {
        ***How to call child getStudent() method from student component**** 
      }
    if (this.type === 'staff') {
       ***how to call getStaff() method from staff component**** 
      }
    },
  ```

  --Student (Child component)

  ```
   methods: {

   getStudentInfo() {
   if (this.validateForm) return;

   try {
     this.$router.push({
       name: 'student',
     });
   } catch (error) {
  },

    getStudent() {
       this.$emit('getStudentInfo');
    },
   },
  ```

--Staff (Child component)

```
    methods: {

    getStaffInfo() {
    if (this.validateForm) return;
   
    try {
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'staff',
      });
    } catch (error) {
   },
      
     getStaff() {
        this.$emit('getStaffInfo');
     },
    },
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: How can i pass the student and staff child method to parent getInfo

Comment: you want to run a child method based on type in parent component?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Comment: add a prop called type to child components which bound to the parent type then watch that properties inside the children then run the correspondant method

Comment: Could you kindly show an example if you dont mind.

Comment: ok, please make a codesanbox sample in order to debug it